# How do I bind to a right-click event inside a Class object based on a Frame

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter

I'm working on a Class which supports a multi-font Button by embedding multiple widgets inside a Frame. Now I'm trying to be able to handle the class instance calling the `bind()` method, but I can't get it to work. I thought that the Class would simply inherit the `bind()` method from the Frame, but it doesn't seem to be working in this instance. When I right-click on the second Button (a class instance), I do not get my printed statement. What am I doing wrong?
Sample to reproduce issue:

```
import tkinter as tk

class ButtonF(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, **options):
        self.command = options.pop('command', None)
        text = options.pop('text', '')
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **options)
        self.b = tk.Button(master, text=text, command=self.command)
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self._click)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self._release)
        self.b.pack()

    def _click(self):
        self.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        if self.command:
            self.command()

    def _release(self):
        self.config(relief=tk.RAISED)

    def bind(self, *a, **kw):
        tk.Frame.bind(self, *a, **kw)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Frame Button')
    root.but1 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 1 (Regular)', command=lambda *a:print('Button 1 Click!'))
    root.but1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    root.but2 = ButtonF(root, text='Button 2 (ButtonF)', command=lambda *a:print('Button 2 Click!')) # 
    root.but2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    root.but1.bind('<Button-3>', lambda *a: print('Button 1 Right-Click!'))
    root.but2.bind('<Button-3>', lambda *a: print('Button 2 Right-Click!')) #### THIS DOESN'T WORK ####
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ButtonF` is inherited from `tk.Frame`.  When you do:

```
root.but2.bind('<Button-3>', lambda *a: print('Button 2 Right-Click!'))
```

You are binding to the frame and not to the button within the frame (which has the master set to `root`).

To get your expected behavior, you have to pass the binding to the button:

```
def bind(self, *a, **kw):
    tk.Frame.bind(self.b, *a, **kw)
```

Answer (score 0):

The final trick was to bind to both the frame and the button. So, binding to both `self` and `self.b`.
Why? Well, you have to bind to the frame in case you click on part of the frame that is not under the button. And you have to bind to the button in case you click on the button itself (i.e. not on part of the frame).
So, two bindings are necessary for a proper solution.